# How to disable adding Timestamp through Macro when cell is just clicked but not edited?

Tags: excel, vba

I've added some VBA code for a timestamp & user name to a task-tracking file. While the code I found for this works and adds the information where needed, the macro reacts to single clicks and enters the time of the click instead the time of value change.

I tried various codes and this is the one I ended up with. The task status is in Column "I", and I want the timestamp to appear in Column "K" and User Name in column "L". The Code is placed within the Sheet.

```
Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 9 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(Target.Row, 11).Value = Date + Time
Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = UserName
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

I want to add a timestamp & user name only when cell value is changed, e.g. from "Open" to "Done". I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_Change` event instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

Comment: ^ Should be an easy change (very horrible pun intended): get rid of the `Selection` in `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question out: you want the [`Worksheet_Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event instead of [`Worksheet_SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange).

To fix, simply remove the `Selection` in `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was easier than it appeared to be... If you can, could you please tell me a bit about these two events? I'm the "copy/paste" type when it comes to VBA, but I want to learn as well. This was the first time I used this type of event.

Comment: I edited the question with the links to the documentation, but briefly, the selection change event occurs when the selection changes on the worksheet - so any time new cell(s) are selected. The change event occurs when a cell is changed by the user or an external link. The cell value changing from "Open" to "Done" is the latter case.